# PHP SoapClient - connect to wsdl Operation timed out

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I'm stuck with connection to wsdl of our business partner through PHP SoapClient and I will be grateful for any advise.

**WSDL:** http://ora-im.cscargo.cz:7788/orabpel/secure/GPSlocations/GPSlocations?wsdl

**Endpoint:** http://ora-im.cscargo.cz:7788/orabpel/secure/GPSlocations

When I try create SoapClient than warning is fire with message

> "failed to open stream: Operation timed out"

Code:

```
$wsdl = 'http://ora-im.cscargo.cz:7788/orabpel/secure/GPSlocations/GPSlocations?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient( $wsdl );
```

Thank you guys for any reply!

Comment: Maybe they didn't provided you access to this WebService by IP? Try to open this link in your machine browser.

Comment: Maybe a firewall rule or some kind of vpn connection is required to access the url. Please contact your IT business partner or read the security section of the documentation.

Comment: thank you guys for replay! i will try contact them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i try to open the links in the browser they do not work.
So what i think is that they have:

1. Some kind of firewall that prevents arbitrary connections:
2. The urls are not those.

So what should you do is to talk with the support of the system and ask them for some debug information. At least this is what i do.